# bash script to find total number of permuations

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permutation

I am writing a `bash` script to find the total no. of permutations (used in mathematics)
whose formula is **n!/(n-r)!**, but the script that I used gives different output value than the expected one.  Anyone to figure out my mistake?  I am newbie in `bash` scripting.

```
echo "Enter no. to find factorial"
read num 
fact=1
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
fact=`expr $num \* $fact`
num=`expr $num - 1`
done

echo "Enter value for r"
read num1
num2=$((num-num1))

fact1=1
while [ $num2 -gt 0 ]
 do
fact1=`expr $num2 \* $fact1`
num2=`expr $num2 - 1`
done

echo "Total no. of permutations $((fact/fact1)) "
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question sounds like a homework question to me. If this is so, you take away your chance of learning something by asking for a solution. In your case you destroy your chance on learning how to debug a problem. A look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions might also be helpful.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to call another program (`expr`), since Bash is perfectly able to compute integer arithmetics (see `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` in man bash). The following snippet might help you:

```
fact=1     
for ((i=4; i>1; i--)) do
  ((fact*=i))
done
echo $fact

#echo $((4+4))  # Arithmetic Expansion might also be useful
```

**Output**

```
24
```

Answer (score 1):

I think OP's code and @bgoldst solution can be improved because both will fail when **`n`** and **`r`** are big due to that the key of the algorithm is the use of factorial, and this, as you already should know, produces huge integer numbers which `bash` cannot handle. `bash` arithmetic is limited to 32-bit signed integers.

For instance, let's say **`n`** is 49 and **`r`** is 2, the @bgoldst's script shows -6 -- the right value is 2352 (49*48). When **`n`** is 32 and **`r`** is 2, the output is 0 -- the right value is 992 (32*31).

@bgoldst improves the OP's code but he adds no intelligence to the algorithm -- Have you forgotten we are programmers?

**Mathematical background**

The expression **`n!/(n-r)!`** can be re-written this way

```
  n!      n·(n-1)·(n-2)···(n-r+1) · (n-r)!
------ = --------------------------------- = n·(n-1)·(n-2)···(n-r+1)
(n-r)!              (n-r)!
```

Pay attention to that the **`r`** value is actually the number of factors in the ultimate multiplication.

For example, when **`n=49`** and **`r=2`**

```
   49!       49!      49·48·47!
--------- = ----- = ------------- = 49·48 = 2352
 (49-2)!     47!         47!
```

**My solution**

My solution uses the **`bc`** tool in order to bypass the constrains of 32-bit fixed-point arithmetic and **`seq`** tool to remove any shell loop.

Provided that the **`n`** and **`r`** values are well formed positive integers:

```
# Check if n>=r
if   [ "$( bc <<<$n'>='$r 2>/dev/null)" != 1 ]
then
     echo "r cannot be bigger than n"
     exit 1
fi

PERMUTATIONS=$( seq -s '*' $((n-r+1)) "$n" | bc )

echo "Total no. of permutations for n=$n and r=$r is ${PERMUTATIONS:-1}"
```

notes:

- `bc <<<$n'>='$r 2>/dev/null` prints either 0 or 1, no matter how big **`n`** and **`r`** are. In the case when **`n`** or **`r`** are not well formed integer values, `bc` command will claim, report an error message and print nothing (NULL string). Pay attention to the fact that, if my code has to admit huge integers which cannot be properly handled by `bash`, then it cannot contain `bash` usual arithmetic comparisons such as `[ "$n" -ge "$r" ]`, `[[ "$n" >= "$r" ]]` or  `(( n >= r ))`. That is why `bc` is used here too.
- `seq -s '*'`  would produce, for instance, `4*5*6*7` which is piped to the `bc` command.
- When **`r`** is zero, no matter **`n`** is, the `seq` command line produces nothing (empty). Therefore, `PERMUTATIONS="${PERMUTATIONS:-1}"` is necessary to provide a default value (1).
- The `bc` command (as well as `dc`) prints the huge numbers in several lines (please read the manual pages); consequently my code will print it **as it is**.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you destroy the value of `$num` in your first factorial loop, but then you try to use it again post-loop. The value of `$num` always ends up at zero after said loop, so `$((num-num1))` will end up being negative and the conditional `$num2 -gt 0` will always be false on the first evaluation. You can solve this problem by copying the variable and destroying the copy.

Other recommendations:

- Use single-quoted strings instead of double-quoted when you don't need interpolation, since single-quoted strings disallow interpolation completely. It's safer that way. People get burned on accidental double-quoted interpolation all the time. Here's a good example: [Assignment issue with Rscript -e calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367637/assignment-issue-with-rscript-e-calls/36368380#36368380).
- It's better to use `$[...]` for arithmetic evaluation instead of `$((...))` because you save two characters.
- Never use `` `expr ...` `` for arithmetic evaluation since that requires a fork and complicates parsing (e.g. you had to backslash-escape asterisks, which is undesirable). (And I'm not sure why you sometimes chose that idiom, when you are obviously aware of the `$((...))` construct for arithmetic expressions.) I suggest you consistently use `$[...]` for all arithmetic evaluation.
- It's better to use `[[ ... ]]` for conditionals, since it's more powerful than `[ ... ]` and has a cleaner syntax by virtue of being a shell keyword, whereas the single-bracket command is a mere builtin. (If you don't believe me, try running `type [ [[`.) Even when you don't require the more advanced capabilities of the double-bracket command you should still use it, for consistency in all your code, and, again, for the cleaner syntax.
- Since multiplying by 1 has no effect, you can change the `-gt 0` tests to `-gt 1`.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

## get n
echo 'Enter no. to find factorial';
read n;

## compute n!
nFact=1;
temp1=$n;
while [[ $temp1 -gt 1 ]]; do
    nFact=$[temp1*nFact];
    temp1=$[temp1-1];
done;

## get r
echo 'Enter value for r';
read r;

## compute (n-r)!
nrFact=1;
temp1=$[n-r];
while [[ $temp1 -gt 1 ]]; do
    nrFact=$[temp1*nrFact];
    temp1=$[temp1-1];
done;

echo "Total no. of permutations $[nFact/nrFact]";
```

Comment: *"$[...] is old syntax that should not be used anymore."* according to Bash's manual and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2415777/1671066. I'd suggest your edit your answer and rewrite the relevant parts.

Comment: @bgoldst No I did not downvote you, why would I, your answer seems helpful to me. (But it is good that you asked, seeing how easily it is to assume otherwise.) I do however disagree with your opinion and reasoning. (And hope that you agree, that your fury is misdirected.)